# SASS - Why is this mixin not being included?

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to SASS, so please bear with me if this seems glaringly obvious.

I have some test SASS code:

```
$background : "yellow";
$color : "green";

%my-placeholder { 

  background: $background;
  color: $color;

}

@mixin my-mixin($background,$color) {

  %my-placeholder { 

    background: $background;
    color: $color;

  }

}

.my-class {

  /* Why does this 'my-mixin()' NOT get included to the class? */
  @include my-mixin($background,$color);
  color: blue;

}
```

It's a combination of variables, placeholders and mixins, which outputs:

```
.my-class {
  /* Why does this 'my-mixin()' NOT get included to the class? */
  color: blue;
}
```

As you can see, the @include of the mixin, which holds a call to overwrite a placeholder, doesn't get used within the .my-class selection. Why is this?

I have a SASS-meister where you can see this live:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/8015459

Is this normal behaviour? Are there dependencies which I'm missing in order to use this feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Bro what is that `%` represent too?

Comment: @VivekVikranth it's a [extend only selelector (or placeholder)](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders)

Answer (score 1):

It is being included but you're just not calling it. `%` is a placeholder selector so you need to `@extend %my-placeholder` after you call the mixin. This will still end up with something you probably aren't expecting.

```
.my-class {
  color: blue;
}
.my-class .my-class {
  background: "yellow";
  color: "green";
}
```

I think you might be better off with a simple mixin since you need to switch the variables up.

```
@mixin my-mixin( $background: #ccc, $color: #000 ){
  background: $background;
  color: $color;
}

.my-class {
  @include my-mixin( red, green );
}
```

Also, it seems you might be thinking that a variable defined inside a selector will make it local, this isn't the case. It definitely threw me for a loop while I was learning.

```
$color: red;

.foo {
  $color: blue;
  color: $color; // $color is blue...
}

.bar {
  color: $color; // $color is still blue, not red...
}
```

Comment: Actually, in a future version of Sass, variables defined within a selector *will* have a different scope.  Compiling your last piece of sample code under Sass 3.3 (beta), you'll get a deprecation warning regarding overwriting/using global variables.  The change in scoping behavior won't happen until 3.4, though.

Comment: I like the sound of that even though I rarely find myself doing it.